# How do you persist a completed PDF form without downloading it to the client first?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, adobe

We are creating an application for employee onboarding for the HR department.  Part of this application's functionality is to display tax forms for the new employee to fill out.  The IRS provides PDFs that have fields that can be entered directly into the PDF.

I've been asked if we can display the form to the user in the context of the page, using the browser to display it, and then when the user is finished and clicks a "Save" button, we would then save that completed form into a document storage application.

I was under the impression that we had two options: collect the user data in an HTML form and then generate the form programatically or present the form to be filled in, force the user to download their work, and then upload the completed form to us.

Is there a third option to allow us to "live edit and persist" a PDF without putting any files on the client?  If so, could you point me to sample code, documentation, etc?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is... but not in a way that will behave consistently in all browsers and all devices. You'd need to limit your users to using IE and Adobe Reader as a plug-in... which I don't recommend.

The problem is that many browsers, in fact, most of the newest versions, all have their own internal PDF viewer and no longer support using Adobe Reader as a plug-in. This means that you'll get a slightly different PDF experience when the PDF is rendered and a vastly different experience when that PDF is a form.

To create the highest level of consistency and control over the filling process, collect the data using some means (HTML as you suggest), populate the form on your server, flatten it, meaning remove the interactivity leaving the data in place, and then present the completed **static** form to user in the browser and ask them to "confirm" that it's been filled correctly. At this point they can download it if they want to but a download isn't required. This removes the potential problems created when non-Adobe viewers are used to fill forms and provides a consistent experience for the end user regardless of platform or browser.